# Why am i getting an exception at dynamic_cast after filling object with zeros using memset

Tags: c++, inheritance, memcpy, dynamic-cast, memset

I am getting this weird runtime exception with dynamic_cast, but only if i fill the the object i'm casting with zeros using `memset`, or just copying some data into it with `memcpy` . Here's an example that generates the exception.

```
class Base
{
public:
    virtual void func() { }
};

class Derived : public Base
{
public: 
    void func() override { }    
};

int main()
{   
    Derived derived;
    Base* base_ptr = &derived;
    memset(base_ptr, 0, sizeof(Derived));

    Derived* derived_ptr = dynamic_cast<Derived*>(base_ptr);    
}
```

And the exception message is:[image]

I get the same exception if i copy one `Derived` object to another using memcpy.
Anyone got any idea whats going on, is it messing up the RTTI that `dynamic_cast` uses?

I am making a Game Engine and in it is a entity component system, and at one point in the program i load all the Objects and their components from a file. The way i implemented different components is using inheritance (each component derives from one base component). When i load the objects, and its components i cant just allocate the amount of memory that the component takes, i have to use new *component name*, because only then dynamic_cast works.

I am using Visual Studio 2019.

Comment: What is it that you wish to accomplish with the `memset` that could not be accomplished by defining a default constructor that performs zero initialization, or a method that does the same?

Comment: i made an edit that explains why am i using dynamic_cast and the whole context of the situation.

Comment: @Mark I don't understand this : *"When i load the objects, and its components i cant just allocate the amount of memory that the component takes"* Why not? *"I have to use new component name, because only then dynamic_cast works"* It isn't clear to me what this means.

Comment: If i just allocate some memory and use static_cast to cast it to a component pointer the dynamic_cast wont work, it wont know which component its supposed to be, does it?

Comment: I'm not sure what you need, but it sounds like you want [placement new](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/new). Beware that it is tricky. You'll need to manually call the created objects' destructor. You can't use `memset` or `memcpy` with types that have `virtual` members.

Comment: Your explanatory text does not make clear why you need `memset`. Did you serialize your objects in some way and store them in the file, and now you wish to restore it? Or, is the file used to configure your system?

Comment: @jxh I'm not *using* `memset`, i;m using `memcpy` to copy data from a file, but i thought that the question would be simpler to explain with `memset`. Idk

Comment: But if i define an assigment operator i wont know wich to call because i dont know the type. So i guess i have to implement RTTI

Comment: Can you explain how `memcpy` is able to know the type in a way that an assignment operator cannot?

Comment: @jxh i didnt know that it was a wrong way to go because i didnt know that there are some hidden virtual function pointers in the class. I tought it would be enough, but turns out it isnt. I implemented ids for each component type and then for each id i have a pointer to a function that copies object of the right type to another one

Comment: Honestly, you have not illustrated the problem you are trying to solve. You are only describing an issue with using `memcpy` / `memset` on a class with virtual methods. If you could provide an illustration of what you want to accomplish, a solution might become more obvious to those trying to help you.

Comment: @jxh the issue was i didnt know there were hidden virtual function pointers, all the other "component" stuff is for context

Answer (score 5):

Your code has undefined behavior.  `memset` requires that the object that it is setting be [*TriviallyCopyable*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/TriviallyCopyable), which yours is not because it has virtual functions.

The consequence of this is that you are overwriting the data in the class that the compiler uses for polymorphism and as such it can't resolve the cast as that information is now garbage.

Comment: Thank you for the response! Any idea how i can go around this issue? Is there an easy solution?

Comment: @Mark Don't do the `memset`?  Without knowing what you are actually trying to accomplish, that's about all I can suggest.

Comment: @Mark That still doesn't help on why you are using `memset`.  Ideally you should have a `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<component>` as your storage for all of the derived classes and then you can use `make_unique` instead of `new`.

Comment: I'm not *using* `memset`, i;m using `memcpy` to copy data from one object to another, but i thought that the question would be simpler to explain with `memset`. Idk

Comment: @mark, memcpy has the same requirement.  You shouldn't need to use either of your using pointers

Comment: Define an assignment operator or a conversion operator. Using `memcpy` is wrong for your object-oriented design.

Answer (score 3):

A class with virtual methods often has a *hidden* pointer member for the vtable.  By using `memset` you are destroying that pointer.

The hidden pointer is not required by the C++ language specification, but it is by far the most common way of implementing virtual methods and RTTI.

Comment: Thank you for the response! Any idea how i can go around this issue?

Comment: @Mark stop using `memset`.  It's a holdover from C that isn't meant to be used on objects.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux that is true, but do you know of a compiler that works differently than how I describe it?  Sometimes using a concrete description of what goes on under the hood makes things easier to understand.

Comment: "Sometimes using a concrete description of what goes on under the hood makes things easier to understand." unfortunately quite often that leads to misunderstanding which later difficult to get rid of.